# setting td inner text through script called in razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, syntax

I want to do something like this within my view (razor)

```
if(index == @:{<script>{getPosition(@geResult.assessmentId);}</script>}){
     geResult.ResultValue;
   }
```

What will be the proper syntax?

**Full HTML**

```
 <tr>
 @{
    var index = 4; 
    foreach(Assessment geAssessment in Model.assessments)
     {
     <td>
      @foreach (ShortResult geResult in Model.results)
      {
       if(geResult.StudentID == geStudent.studentid)
       {
         if(index == @:{<script>{getPosition(@geResult.assessmentId);}</script>} ){
        geResult.ResultValue;
        }
      }
    }
   </td>
   index++;
   }
  }
</tr>
```

**UPDATE**

I am trying the other way round now can anyone guide me please

**SCRIPT**

```
   function getPosition(id, colIndex) {

    var element = '#' + id;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(colIndex).html("A");
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(colIndex).html());
    return $(element).index();

  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <td>
   @foreach (ShortResult geResult in Model.results)
     {
      if(geResult.StudentID == geStudent.studentid)
      {
       <script>{ getPosition(@geResult.assessmentId, @index); }</script>
     }
     }
 </td>
```

now the alert returns undefined although i am setting its value (text) just before!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, after wasting a whole 1.5 days i am able to solve this! hope it helps someone.

**SCRIPT**

```
function getPosition(id, colIndex, resultValue) {

    var element = '#' + id;

    var cell = $('.test').closest('tr').children('td').get(colIndex);
    if($(element).index() == colIndex){
        cell.innerHTML = resultValue;
    }
```

}

**HTML**

```
<tr>
     @{
var index = 4; 
foreach(Assessment geAssessment in Model.assessments)
 {
<td class="test">
  @foreach (ShortResult geResult in Model.results)
  {
    if(geResult.StudentID == geStudent.studentid)
     {
      if (geResult.ResultValue != null) { 

       <script>{ getPosition(@geResult.assessmentId, @index, '@geResult.ResultValue'); }</script>
       }
     }
     }
    </td>
   index++;
 }
}
</tr>
```

Comment: Answer does not provide any explanation of the problem or solution -  so not really useful for future visitors.